# Can I assign an onClick() function to my various SliverPersistentHeader to jump to that position in the CustomScrollView?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver, sliver-grid, sliverappbar

I have successfully built my `CustomScrollView()` that contains `SliverGrid()` items and `SliverPersistentHeaders()` which are pinned. I want a click on any `SliverPersistentHeader()` to scroll to the exact position. I want to know if this is possible in flutter.